# can't use arr.length in a array passes in a generic method

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
            print_generic(arr);
        }

        public static <T> void print_generic(T arr) { 
//        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  //ERROR
//            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
//        }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(arr);
        }

    }
```

error : can not resolve symbol length

what is the issue
plz tell me what I am doing wrong

[**java visualizer image**: even both the arr refers to the same object :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jOFN.png)

Comment: `T` is not necessarily an array, so as far as compiler is concerned, there is no `length` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter of your method must be an array

```
public static <T> void print_generic(T[] arr) { }
```